# Fulltext e Números

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma tabela de busca com um índice FullText.

Quando busco uma palavra, ex: tecnologia, ele busca normal.

Mas se buscar um númer, exmplo 8530. ele não retorna nada.

Comment: O índice só interfere no tempo de retorno na busca, não nos resultados retornados, então não é culpa do índice _FullText_. Coloque exemplos das suas consultas que funcionam e não funcionam.  
E seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, seria interessante você dá uma lida no tour [pt.stackoverflow.com/tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel! Eu consegui resolver o problema. A questão é que campos LONGTEXT e MEDIUMTEXT não são indexamos como Fulltext na versão do Mysql que estava usando.

Comment: Mas esse problema com índice influenciava no retorno de um `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver o problema. A questão é que campos LONGTEXT e MEDIUMTEXT não são indexamos como Fulltext na versão do Mysql que estava usando.